# User's authorization in Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to programming,now I'm writing Java Swing application.  One of the main tasks is to provide user's authorization (admin, unregistered/registered user).  I don't now the best way to realize it.  Please give me advice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps can be...

1. Make a database that contains username/password. [You may also have other system to store username/password instead of database based on your need.]
2. Create a login frame that asks for username/password.
3. On click of Login button check entered username/password with that in database.
4. If correct username/password then show next frame or show error.

Comment: Thanks.What about different privileges?For example,admin "sees" everything and can edit all information,unregistered can only view information,registered edit information entered by himself.What is programming solution of this?

Comment: @user628480: make another role table which contains entries for different role and give reference of this table to login table. [You can also add role column in login table instead of creating new role table] Now after login is successful check for user's role in database and do appropriate action.