# Problems with JTable and question about authorization and authentication

Tags: java, swing, authentication, jtable

I'm writting simple Swing application. I can't uderstand why column name isn't displayed? Here is my code:

```
public class HistoryFrame extends JFrame{
public JTable tbProducts=new JTable();
public JButton makePayButton;
public JPanel panel;
    public PaymentServiceInterface paymentService=new PaymentService();
public HistoryFrame(){
    setTitle("History of Payments");
    setSize(500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    panel=new JPanel();
    this.add(panel);
    DisplayData(paymentService.getData());
    ActionListener makePayAction=new PayAction(); 
    addRegUserButton("Make Payment",makePayAction);
    setVisible(true); 
}
public JButton addRegUserButton(String label, ActionListener listener){
    makePayButton=new JButton(label);
    makePayButton.addActionListener(listener);
    panel.add(makePayButton);
    return makePayButton;
}
private void DisplayData(List<Payment> objectList) {

    DefaultTableModel aModel = new DefaultTableModel() {
    //setting the jtable read only

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return false;
    }
    };
    //setting the column name
    Object[] tableColumnNames = new Object[3];
    tableColumnNames[0]="User";
    tableColumnNames[1] ="Payment";
    tableColumnNames[2]="Date";

    aModel.setColumnIdentifiers(tableColumnNames);
    if (objectList == null) {
    this.tbProducts.setModel(aModel);
    return;
    }
    Object[] objects = new Object[3];
    ListIterator<Payment> lstrg = objectList.listIterator();
    //populating the tablemodel
    while (lstrg.hasNext()) {
    Payment p = lstrg.next();                                         
    objects[0]=p.getUser().getName();
    objects[1]=p.getPayment();
    objects[2]=p.getDate();
    aModel.addRow(objects);
    }
    //binding the jtable to the model
    this.tbProducts.setModel(aModel);
    panel.add(tbProducts);
}
```

I want to know how I can provide user authorization and authentication in swing application? Something like in web apps when there is session and I put in it, for example, user name and I able to get it anywhere. In this app one of the task provide registered user payment but how I can get his name after log in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting your JTable into a JScrollPane is the easiest way to get a decent display of the column headers.  If you haven't done so, you'll want to go through the Oracle Swing Tutorials JTable section: [How to Use Tables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Also, it appears that you've already asked about user authorization etc and received an accepted answer here: [User's authorization in Java Swing application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041945/users-authorization-in-java-swing-application).